# Read multiple records set using SQL Reader

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I'm executing multiple stored procedures using a single stored procedure. Each record set has unique table name to differentiate record sets. Eg:

```
record set 1:
    Id |Title               | RowNumber|TableName
    1  |TimePro - Timesheets| 1        |CompanyLinksPo

record set 2:
    Id  |CategoryName | RowNumber|TableName
    111 |Fruits       | 1        |FruitCategory
```

Number of record sets getting changed based on the parameters. I'm using sql reader to read these records sets. I have tried following way to read the records sets.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  ......                    
}
reader.NextResult();
while (reader.Read())
{
  .....
}
...
```

The issue I'm facing is, since number of record sets getting changed, I need to write this while loop dynamically rather than hard coding number of loops using `reader.NextResult();`. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this process?

Comment: Well `NextResult()` returns a `bool`, so you can loop. It's hard to know what you're doing in the "..." bits though - if that changes for each result set, it's not clear what you'd expect to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet it repeats the same while loop. Let's say I'm executing 3 sps inside parent one, so I had 3 while loops. I wanted it to be a dynamic one.

Comment: I think the better solution to your problem is to store all the data in a data set.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a do/while loop where the while condition calls NextResult.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think shadow is correct here - each of the result sets returned from the stored procedure have a different set of columns - a simple while loop will not be a sufficient solution.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Look at the OP's answer where I ask what the code using the results is like: "it repeats the same while loop". In that case, an outer while loop *would* be a sufficient solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've read that, but also looked at the record sets in the question's body...

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes, they're different - but maybe that isn't important based on what's in the while loop, e.g. they're being fetched with reflection, or just counted, or... who knows.

Comment: The op, I guess...

Comment: Thanks for the support. I used simple loop to do my job. But not sure whether this is the correct way.  Inside the loop CompanyLink c = new CompanyLink();
                                    SqlHelper.CreateBusinessEntityFromQuery(reader, c);
                                    itemList.CompanyLinks.Add(c); goes like that.